# Delete all iptables DROP rules with a specific IP

Tags: iptables

I have multiple iptables entry, which DROP packets from different IPs on different ports.
I would like to delete with one command all the rules matching a specific IP. From

```
man iptables
```

it seems be possible. How can I do this?

Comment: man iptables can use to find a information for your requirement.

Comment: Here's a tip!  Use **ipset** to extract the majority of ip addresses out of iptables.

Comment: @ErandaPeiris I said I checked on `man` and there is not any reference about that

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do this with a simple iptables command - there may be some frankenhack bash script you can use depending in your version of Linux (I'm thinking an iptables dump, grep,restore)

What you can do is insert an iptables rule at the start of the table to allow from that IP which will override everything that comes afterwards. Something like

```
 iptables -I INPUT -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT
 iptables -I INPUT -d X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables-save|grep -v 192\.168\.1\.1 >iptables-save && iptables -F && iptables-restore </iptables.save
```

You may have to use \ to delimited the period symbol

This will **not** match CIDR notation.

1. Looking for 192.168.0.0/16 will **not** find 192.168.1.1.
2. Searching for 192.168.1.1 will **not** match against 192.168.0.0/16 either.

Explaination:

1. iptables-save                      #save the config
2. grep -v                            # -v is exclude matching lines
3. > iptables-save                     # dump the new result to iptables-save
4. && iptables -F                     # when done,flush all rules
5. && iptables-restore

Answer (score 0):

Adamm, the maker of skynet had made a script for exactly this for his iptables firewall; Hopefully this should do the trick. https://github.com/Adamm00/IPSet_ASUS/commit/56f4bad86ac64bf9c74c6d588f4cd2d83265ab1a